# What's the point of telling your Companion to sleep?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I found that I can order my companion (Lydia in my case, but guess it doesn't matter) to sleep by pointing at the bed while in "command mode".

What is the point of this? Many of the other commands have some real use, for example asking them to pick things, attack something etc.

I tried to join the companion in bed (yeah I know :)) but once I got out of "command mode" she got out of bed so that failed miserably as well.

Any other ideas? The only thing I can think of right now is maybe let the companion sleep for several hours, then they will get the rest bonus? If so, can this be proven somehow?

Comment: Maybe they put it into the game to cover all interactions and make it more realistic - telling them to sit on a chair has also no use, but you can do it. Therefore, I think telling them to sleep has no use, unless it is needed in a quest you can make with the construction set.

Comment: Hey shadow, I want thank you for answering many of mine and the comunitys questions, cute baby btw

Comment: I think "All other commands have some real use, for example asking him/her to pick things, attack something etc" is a false premise, since you can actually have them use a chair, or a forge, without any special effect

Comment: Does this also happen if you are married to the character? I know you have to sleep in proximity to your spouse in order to receive the Lover's Comfort buff.

Comment: @Mezner I'm still single (in the game) so can't tell.. will check this out soon as I've put my eyes on very handsome lady already.

Answer (score 11):

I can think of one possibility: If you were a vampire and needed to feed. It's easier to have your meal follow you around…

Comment: How would that work with "once I got out of "command mode" she got out of bed"?

Comment: vampire teeth smiley has to be :[

Comment: @Gumbz, there should be enough time after the order for you to feed, since its instantaneous.

Comment: @yx. why did you delete your answer? I was just going to upvote it..

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Because I realized your companion doesn't really go to sleep, per say, you are just telling them to interact with something (i.e. use this item).  I got that quest mixed up with another one where you tell someone to sleep on an altar, but that's not done via command mode.

Comment: Being a vampire has nothing to do with sleep benefits. Sorry, but that's not making any sense. Shadow Wizard didn't mention anything about being a vampire. For example, I've heard there is a benefit when you get married and this may be why the person can command someone to go to bed. Though I am not sure as I haven't tried it.

Comment: @Alex, How about Σ:

Comment: @eazimmerman the sum of all teeth?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [skull of corruption](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skull_of_Corruption#Skull_of_Corruption) on them. It's very useful, since using the skull on someone while sleeping increases its attack power by 50. You can use that in middle of a cave by finding something the companion could sleep on.

Comment: Sorry this is totally not relevant to my question.

Comment: it is valid if you know what the skull of corruption does.  It requires you to feed on someone's dreams in order to power it up, and having a follower sleep is a great way to feed on dreams as long as there's a bed nearby.  This and the vampire bit is probably the two best ways to take advantage of a sleeping companion.

Comment: yes but when vampire feed he become weaker and when the skull feed it becomes stronger, thus you can sometimes find beds inside caves so you can fill it there.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your answer as you talked about the increase in attack power. Anyway, as Jonathan said in comment to [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/46708/7652) all those actions are "dummy" so I believe that even if the follower *appears* to be sleeping, he won't be really sleeping and you won't be able to harvest any dreams. Unless you tried it and it worked?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think they *put it in the game* like some say. From a programmers point of view I can tell you it's most likely just not turned off. I haven't experimented much with command mode on my followers, but can't you just interact with all objects that you as a player otherwise could? If so, that means it's just default. Also the reason why companions can't produce anything on tanning racks etc is because command mode doesn't include the menu choices.
Hope this answer wasn't too boring, but it's probably just as boring as this :-)

Comment: Not boring, but bit too.. technical. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 3):

My companion (Lydia) yawns occasionally. I found telling her to sleep stops this from happening for about a week.

Comment: Interesting.. never saw her yawn but maybe I didn't look close enough. If that's true that's the winning answer so far! :)

Comment: Oh... you have the PS3 version right? PC for me and looks like there are many differences this might be one of them. :-/

Comment: Yes PS3 version.

Comment: Oh and I hear her yawn, but I am not sure if there is an animation for it.

Comment: Well I know it doesn't count unless someone ELSE confirms it but I heard it again today. NPC